# How to Avoid Resiliency of InstallShield

Tags: installshield-2012, basic-msi

I have a Basic MSI project that installs some dlls to a location say `"C:\Program Files (x86)\CompanyA\Service"`. The folder access permissions restricts access to standard account (non administrator). Now I launch the application using a standard account, which doesn't uses the DLL's in the above said location. But due to the resiliency feature of InstallShield, it tries to check the components. As the above component is not accessible it starts self repairing process showing a dialog "Please wait while windows configures ProductA" .

Is there any option to turn off this resiliency feature? Or Is there any way to hide the Re-installation dialog?

Please suggest if we have any other solution for the above problem.

Comment: Why is the dll not readable for the standard user? It is ok that they don't have write access, but read access is normal to allow. If you blank out the component GUID for the dll in question, MSI will install the file but never run any self-repair for it, nor will it uninstall it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

- you can put a install condition on your components to validate the `Privileged`property and not install those particular components on the machine. that way the installer will not think it have missing parts.
- you can install it elsewhere, where you have the right to.
- MSI 5.0 have a feature to make a dual purpose package that can be install as user or as admin.
- you can also deploy the dll as a support file and copy it via a batch files. 
  (not a best practice but it could work)